# Create a Parent/child Data Structure from a Simple List

Tags: java

I have a flat list like following.

```
nodeA           
 nodeB           
  nodeC           
  endnodeC   
  nodeD
  endnodeD
 endnodeB
endnodeA
```

Is there any way to create parent child data structure in java like folliwng.

```
   A               
   |              
   B             
  / \            
 C   D
```

Comment: What do you mean by saying "is there any way" to do this? I don't think there is an off-the-shelf function which will do this for you. But this is certainly possible and easy recursive programming. It actually looks like a homework problem. I don't think anybody will give you the full solution here, instead you should try to make some progress and ask more specific questions.

Comment: Please consider tagging this as homework if it is. It really sounds like it.

Answer (score 3):

assume the result node is something like :

```
class Node {
    Node parent;
    // other data
}
```

psuedo code for generating from your flat list is (assume the flatNodes list is in correct structure and pairs):

```
Node currentNode;
foreach (n in flatNodes) {
  if (n is endnode) {
    currentNode = currentNode.parent
  } else {
    Node newNode = createNodeBaseOnFlatNode(n);
    newNode.parent=currentNode;
    currentNode = newNode;
  }
}
```

Comment: On the money! Aaah, brings me back to the days of implementing tree structures in C. I miss pointers...

Answer (score 0):

Is this a binary tree? Look at http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Collections-Data-Structure/BinaryTree.htm

Comment: You should read the question more clearly. There are specific terms under which a new child should be spawned. This does not look like a binary tree. Each time an endNodeX is reached you pop back to the parent. Potentially each node can have more than two children.